# How to cancel / undo sorting in a Windows Forms DataGridView

Tags: .net, windows, winforms

If the user clicks an the column header

- the first time the sorting goes to SortOrder.Ascending
- the second time the sorting goes to SortOrder.Descending
- the third time it should go to `SortOrder.None` again

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet achieves the wanted behavior:

```
    SortOrder old_sort_order = SortOrder.None;
    private void dataGridViewLog_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridViewLog.SortedColumn != null && e.ColumnIndex == dataGridViewLog.SortedColumn.Index)
        {
            if (old_sort_order == SortOrder.Descending)
                datatable.DefaultView.Sort = String.Empty;
            old_sort_order = dataGridViewLog.SortOrder;
        }
    }
```